# Calculate rows based on loop

Tags: r, loops, iteration

I'm trying to implement an iterative method to calculate runoff rainfall using the Horton infiltration equation. The code described below implements the first row (`time = 0`).

```
#Entrance
f0=6
f1=1
k=2
dt=0.25
f=0
time= seq(from=0, to=2, by=dt)
inc_rainfall=c(0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.4, 0.6, 0.6)
rainfall_int=inc_rainfall/dt

#fc
gfc = function(fc) {
  f - ((f0 - fc) / k) + ((f1 / k) * log((fc - f1) / (f0 - f1)))}
fc=uniroot(gfc, interval = c(f0, f1))
fc=fc$root

#F'
fl=if(fc>rainfall_int[1]) sum(f,inc_rainfall[1]) else 0

#fc'
gfcl = function(fcl) {
  fl - ((f0 - fcl) / k) + ((f1 / k) * log((fcl - f1) / (f0 - f1)))}
fcl=uniroot(gfcl, interval = c(f0, f1))
fcl=fcl$root

#Fp ou Fs
fporfs=ifelse(fc<rainfall_int[1],f,
       ifelse(fcl<rainfall_int[1],
              (f0-rainfall_int[1])/k-
               f1/k*log((rainfall_int[1]-f1)/(f0-f1)), 0))

#dt'
dtl=ifelse((fc>rainfall_int[1]), 
    ifelse(fcl<rainfall_int[1],
           (fporfs-f)/rainfall_int[1],0),0)

#ts
ts=ifelse(fc<rainfall_int[1],time[1],
   ifelse(fcl<rainfall_int[1],dtl+time[1], 0))

#to
hto = function(to) {
  fporfs-f1*(ts-to)-(f0-f1)/k*(1-exp(-k*(ts-to)))}
to=uniroot(hto, interval = c(0, 1))
to=to$root

#Ft+Dt
ftdt=ifelse(to==0, fl, f1*(time[1]-to)+(f0-f1)/k*(1-exp(-k*(time[1]-to)))) #This value will be the "f" on next row

#Infiltration
infiltr=ftdt+f

#Runoff in line 1
runoff1=inc_rainfall[1]-(ftdt)

#Runoff in line 2 to n
runoffn=inc_rainfall[1]-(ftdt[2]-ftdt[1])

out=as.data.frame(cbind(time[1], inc_rainfall, rainfall_int, f, fc, fl, fcl, 
                        fporfs, dtl, ts, to, ftdt, infiltr, runoff1))

colnames(out)= c("Time", "Incremental Rainfall", "Rainfall Intensity", "F", "fc", "Fl", "Fcl", "Fp or Fs", "dt", "ts", "to", "Ftdt", "Infiltration", "Runoff"    )

out
```

How do I proceed in order that the next row get to be calculated using as the initial value (`f`) the `ftdt` value of the previous row?

Note that in the last column (`runoff`) there is also a change in the function of the first row to the others. Besides that, it will probably also be necessary to add an extra point of `time` (2.25) in order that the variable `ftdt` of the last row get to be calculated.

The expected result can be seen here: http://hydrology.usu.edu/RRP/userdata/4/87/RainfallRunoffProcesses.pdf on page 109.

Comment: Have you tried putting everything in a function and then iterating over the variables in a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you close. I've put your equations in a function which I use in a for loop. I had to change some of your formulas to get it working. I don't know anything about hydrology, but the changes made sense after a glance at the book you link to and a little Wikipedia. The changes also resulted in data that more closely resembles that in the table. Look for `#!!!!!!! <COMMENT> !!!!!!!#` to see what I changed.

On the fifth iteration/row the formula `ftdt=ifelse(to==0, fl, f1*(time-to)+(f0-f1)/k*(1-exp(-k*(time-to))))` produces the wrong result, which screws up the other results. I replaced `f1` with `fc` because it made sense after reading the relevant pages of the book, and the results were closer to what you want. The only thing I'm unsure about is the time variable *t*, which is `time - to` in your formula, i.e. time minus time offset. I think that might be the issue.

```r
compute_horton <- function (f, time, inc_rainfall, rainfall_int) {
    #->->-> calculates runoff rainfall using the Horton infiltration equation

    # constants
    f0=6
    f1=1
    k=2

    #fc
    gfc = function(fc) {
        f - ((f0 - fc) / k) + ((f1 / k) * log((fc - f1) / (f0 - f1)))
    }
    fc=uniroot(gfc, interval = c(f0, f1))
    fc=fc$root

    #F'
    fl=if(fc>rainfall_int) sum(f,inc_rainfall) else 0

    #fc'
    gfcl = function(fcl) {
        fl - ((f0 - fcl) / k) + ((f1 / k) * log((fcl - f1) / (f0 - f1)))
    }
    fcl=uniroot(gfcl, interval = c(f0, f1))
    fcl=fcl$root

    #Fp ou Fs
    fporfs=ifelse(fc<rainfall_int,f,
                  ifelse(fcl<rainfall_int,
                         (f0-rainfall_int)/k-
                             f1/k*log((rainfall_int-f1)/(f0-f1)), 0))

    #dt'
    dtl=ifelse((fc>rainfall_int), 
               ifelse(fcl<rainfall_int,
                      (fporfs-f)/rainfall_int,0),0)

    #ts
    ts=ifelse(fc<rainfall_int,time,
              ifelse(fcl<rainfall_int,dtl+time, 0))

    #to
    hto = function(to) {
        fporfs-f1*(ts-to)-(f0-f1)/k*(1-exp(-k*(ts-to)))
        }
    to=uniroot(hto, interval = c(0, 1))
    to=to$root

    #Ft+Dt - This value will be the "f" on next row
    #!!!!!!! I THINK YOU NEED FC AND NOT F1 !!!!!!!#
    #!!!!!!! EVEN SO, FORMULA DOESN'T WORK QUITE RIGHT !!!!!!!#
    #ftdt=ifelse(to==0, fl, f1*(time-to)+(f0-f1)/k*(1-exp(-k*(time-to))))
    ftdt=ifelse(to==0, fl, fc*(time-to)+(f0-fc)/k*(1-exp(-k*(time-to))))

    #Infiltration
    #!!!!!!! I THINK InFILTRATION IS DIFFERENCE OF FTDT AND F !!!!!!!#
    infiltr=ftdt-f

    #Runoff in line 1
    #!!!!!!! I THINK RUNOFF IS DIFFERENCE OF RAINFALL AND INFILTRATION !!!!!!!#
    runoff1=round(inc_rainfall-infiltr, 3)

    #Runoff in line 2 to n
    #!!!!!!! THIS ISN'T USED ANYWHERE !!!!!!!#
    runoffn=inc_rainfall-(ftdt[2]-ftdt[1]) 

    #### OUTPUT ####
    c(time, inc_rainfall, rainfall_int, f, fc, fl, fcl, fporfs, dtl, ts, to,
      ftdt, infiltr, runoff1
      )
}


# Function input
f=0
dt=0.25
time= seq(from=0, to=2, by=dt)
inc_rainfall=c(0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.4, 0.6, 0.6)
rainfall_int=inc_rainfall/dt

# Matrix column names
cnames <- c("Time", "Incremental Rainfall", "Rainfall Intensity", "F", "fc",
           "Fl", "Fcl", "Fp or Fs", "dt", "ts", "to", "Ftdt", "Infiltration",
           "Runoff"
           )

# Initialize matrix and add column names
hort_mat <- matrix(0, nrow = length(inc_rainfall), ncol = length(cnames))
colnames(hort_mat) <- cnames

for (i in 1:nrow(hort_mat)) {
    hort_mat[i,] <- compute_horton(f = hort_mat[ifelse(i-1 > 0, i-1, i), "Ftdt"],
                                   time = time[i],
                                   inc_rainfall = inc_rainfall[i],
                                   rainfall_int = rainfall_int[i]
                                   )
}
```

Comment: I made some changes in the code, as described below.

Comment: @DiegoStähelin I'm afraid I can't help you very much with the specifics of the calculation because I don't know anything about hydrology. However, the code above works fine, it's just that the calculations are off somewhere. I recommend tweaking the equations in the above code to arrive at the desired result.

Comment: @DiegoStähelin one more thing. Have you had a look at the [HydroMe](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/HydroMe/index.html) R package? It has a function called `SShorton` that returns a Horton water infiltration model.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your contribution, [@gersht](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10191355/gersht). Based on it I cleared the code and inserted `ifelse` functions where there wasn't previously.

However, I still have difficulty using the calculated `ftdt` value in the first row to start the second, on a loop.

Follow the set code. I thought of doing a `for` for each line, but I can't think a way to do this efficiently, keeping the code clean.

```
#Constants
f0=6
f1=1
k=2
dt=0.25
f=0
time= seq(from=0, to=2, by=dt)
inc_rainfall=c(0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.4, 0.6, 0.6)
rainfall_int=inc_rainfall/dt

horton=data.frame(matrix(ncol = 14, nrow = 9))
names(horton)=c("Time", "Incremental Rainfall", "Rainfall Intensity", "F", "fc",
                "Fl", "Fcl", "Fp or Fs", "dt", "ts", "to", "Ftdt", "Infiltration",
                "Runoff")

#g(Fc)
gfc=ifelse (f==0, 

  function(fc) {
  f - ((f0 - fc) / k) + ((f1 / k) * log((fc - f1) / (f0 - f1)))}, 

  function(fc) {
  ftdt[i-1] - ((f0 - fc) / k) + ((f1 / k) * log((fc - f1) / (f0 - f1)))})

fc=uniroot(gfc, interval = c(f0, f1))
fc=fc$root

#F'
fl=ifelse(fc>rainfall_int, f+inc_rainfall, 0)

#fc'
gfcl= ifelse (fl==0,

  0,

  function(fcl) {
  fl - ((f0 - fcl) / k) + ((f1 / k) * log((fcl - f1) / (f0 - f1)))})

fcl=uniroot(gfcl, interval = c(f0, f1))
fcl=fcl$root

#Fp or Fs
fporfs=ifelse(fc<rainfall_int[1],f,
              ifelse(fcl<rainfall_int[1],
                     (f0-rainfall_int[1])/k-
                       f1/k*log((rainfall_int[1]-f1)/(f0-f1)), 0))

#dt'
dtl=ifelse((fc>rainfall_int[1]), 
           ifelse(fcl<rainfall_int[1],
                  (fporfs-f)/rainfall_int[1],0),0)

#ts
ts=ifelse(fc<rainfall_int[1],time[1],
          ifelse(fcl<rainfall_int[1],dtl+time[1], 0))

#to
hto=function(to) {
  fporfs-f1*(ts-to)-(f0-f1)/k*(1-exp(-k*(ts-to)))}

to=uniroot(hto, interval = c(0, 1))
to=to$root

#Ft+Dt
ftdt=ifelse(to==0, fl, f1*(time-to)+(f0-f1)/k*(1-exp(-k*(time-to)))) #Value that starts next row at "gFc"

#Infiltration
infiltr=ifelse(to==0,ftdt-f, ftdt[i]-ftdt[i-1])

runoff=ifelse(time==0, inc_rainfall[i]-(ftdt),  inc_rainfall[i]-(ftdt[i-1]-ftdt[i]))


horton$Time=time
horton$`Incremental Rainfall`=inc_rainfall
horton$`Rainfall Intensity`=rainfall_int
horton$F[1]=f
horton$fc[1]=fc
horton$Fl[1]=fl
horton$Fcl[1]=fcl
horton$`Fp or Fs`[1]=fporfs
horton$dt[1]=dtl
horton$ts[1]=ts
horton$to[1]=to
horton$Ftdt[1]=ftdt
horton$Infiltration[1]=infiltr
horton$Runoff[1]=runoff

horton
```